Show average radial displacement in cylindrical shell modes using integration?
I want to show analytically using integration that the average radial displacement in cylindrical shell mode shapes are zero except when the shell is bending. I'm doing this to validate numerical results where the cylindrical shell response is obtained at the centreline as an average of the circumferential motion.
Here are the nodal patterns for the circumferential modes of a cylindrical shell from n=0 to n=16
As I understand it, there is no bending along the shell for modes of $n > 1$, i.e the centreline of the shell does not move. Therefore, the average dispalcement around the circumference should be equal to zero for an axis-symmetric shell.
For $n = 1$ or bending modes it should be non-zero because the whole circumfernce displaces with no circumferential motion.
The solution that I have been using is shown below; $\bar{u}$ is the average displacement around the circumference of the cylinder for a given value of $n$.
\begin{align}
\bar{u}(\phi) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left(A \sin(n \phi) + B \cos(n \phi)\right) \mathrm{d}\phi.
\end{align}
$A$ and $B$ are just arbitrary amplitude constants, I'm taking them equal to $1$. For every value of $n$ I get zero using the above solution, which makes sense looking at the solution I am using.
I was expecting a non-zero solution for $n = 1$, so it's leading me to think my solution I am using is wrong. Unless the average is taken locally, in which an average displacement of zero for $n = 1$ would be expected?
If not, I am wondering what the correct approach should be?
